# MySQL - Counting number by ID

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have this database (as an example)

[image]

Anyways, I want to make a "most liked" question section but the "likes" are in a different database table hence the `likes`. Anyways, I have the `id` of the question being the same thing in `question_id`... but.. how do I count them in a MYSQL query?

Thanks.

Comment: You should put up a query you've tried. Do you want an actual count? or do you just need the like corresponding to an ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using an `inner join` between your tables, and a `group by` on the question's ids :

```
select question.id, question.question_title, count(*) as num_likes
from question
    inner join likes on likes.question_id = question.id
group by question.id
order by count(*) desc
limit 0, 10
```

This should get you the 10 most-liked questions, with, for each one of those, the number of times it's been liked.

Comment: With `INNER JOIN` it would be possible that there is displayed nothing, when there aren't votes yet.

Comment: true ; but I thought a question with no likes at all is not that much of a liked-question -- up to the OP to use an `inner` or a `left` join, depending on what he prefers ; thanks for pointing that out :-)

Comment: Sure, you're correct, questions with no likes don't belong to the most likes questions :) But I prefer (when set up a new web application) that there are no empty boxes (Google likes content ^^)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.id,x.question_title,x.desc,x.category,COUNT(*) AS likes FROM question x LEFT JOIN likes y ON x.id=y.question_id GROUP BY x.id,x.question_title,x.desc,x.category ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```